# NetScaler Gateway for MAC is not connecting correctly: Protocoll shows "AGAS: Failed to initialise ssl vpn plugin"

Tags: ssl, vpn, mac-osx, citrix, netscaler

I'm using the Citrix Netscaler Gateway for Mac (Version 3.1.8 which is the newest for mac) and macOS High Sierra.

When I use the Gateway Plugin to connect to our gateway, it seems to work, because the the NetScaler starts and shows the popup "Connected to xyz".

But when I try to open a website of the connected vpn, it is not possible.

Now comes the important part - the connection log: cagplugin.log:

```
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{INFO}:{AGAS/AGKEXTInterface:-[AGKEXTInterface sendIoctl:withData:] No IOCTL socket yet.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{WARNING}:{AGAS/AGKEXTInterface:-[AGKEXTInterface createCtlSocket] ioctl(to com.citrix.kernel.sslvpn.control) failed with error 2.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{WARNING}:{AGAS/AGKEXTInterface:-[AGKEXTInterface createIoctlSocket] ioctl(ioctl_info.com.citrix.kernel.sslvpn) failed with error 2.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{WARNING}:{AGAS/Failed to initialize sslvpnPlugin}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{INFO}:{AGAS/AGKEXTInterface:-[AGKEXTInterface sendIoctl:withData:] No IOCTL socket yet.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1782:{INFO}:{Proxy Service Ready <AGEEProxyService: 0x6040000b57e0>.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{INFO}:{AGAS/Packet Filter Service Ready.}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1782:{INFO}:{Client version: 390}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1649:{INFO}:{AGAS/Capturing ARP on device en0}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1782:{INFO}:{Server version: 11.0.63.16}:
{16-12-17:15h50m32s}:1782:{INFO}:{Connected successfully to: gateway.mycompany.de}:
```

I think the important part of this is "AGAS/Failed to initialize sslvpnPlugin".

So it has something to do with an ssl vpn Plugin inside of NetScaler AGAS (which is AG AdminService) that could not be found or not be loaded.

Do you have any idea? I'm totally lost now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: In the mac OS high Sierra there is an extra security setting that blocks some applications for some reasons and that had blocked citrix.

You can find it in the Systems Settings -> Security. And there at the bottom of the window is a hint that shows that some software is blocked.

There is also a button to show the blocked software. You have to find citrix in the list and remove it. After that you have to restart mac.
[image: sorry its in german language but the location is the same;)]

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: This didn't work for me either

Comment: Have you also installed the latest version? Me and my coworkers installed it the latest version and had no problem anymore. I think I got it here: https://www.citrix.com/de-de/downloads/citrix-gateway/earlier-versions/netscaler-gateway-plug-in-448-for-mac.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is reproducible with version 4.4.8. The problem is that macOS 10.15.4 does not offer the possibility to load Netscaler Gateway's extensions. I created a new question with the details: https://serverfault.com/q/1010780/487550

Answer (score 0):

I let here same answer I've wrote here: [Citrix Netscaler Gateway does not work in macOS Catalina 10.15.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/1010780/citrix-netscaler-gateway-does-not-work-in-macos-catalina-10-15-4/1030829#1030829)

I had same issue in MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 and with the Citrix Gateway 4.4.8 (518). The solution was uninstall all Citrix Applications I had (with Finder, moving each one to Trash). Then, I've installed last version available of Citrix Gateway 4.4.8. You must see in Settings icon, inside Security & Privacy icon, to allow the changes performed by Citrix app. After that it requires restart the Mac. Finally, in my case I can't connect by first time using the Citrix Gateway app (maybe you can) but I've login using my company web access, then the App has detect this login and the VPN access is working! by browsers or by CLI. Now, from 2nd time and another, I can login directly from App pushing "Connect". Good luck!